# Cast transactional data

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape, reshape2

I need to `cast` my data:

```
> data.frame(transactionID= c("941214", "941214", "140668","945320","945320","945320"), productCategory = c("A","B","C","B","C","A"))
  transactionID productCategory
1        941214               A
2        941214               B
3        140668               C
4        945320               B
5        945320               C
6        945320               A
```

into this aggregated form:

```
productCategory A.purchase B.purchase C.purchase
A               2          2          1
B               2          2          1
C               1          1          2
```

At `A.purchase` column and `row.number = 1`, I need count transactions in which product A appears.
At `B.purchase` column and `row.number = 1`, I need count transactions in which product B appears together with A.

I tried this: `dcast(data, productCategory~productCategory)`. But it is not counting when product B is together with product A in a transaction.

**SOLUTION:**

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape)
library(tidyr)

> aux = data %>%
     group_by(transactionID)%>%
     tidyr::expand(nesting(productCategory), productCategory) 

> aux
   transactionID productCategory productCategory1
          <fctr>          <fctr>           <fctr>
 1        140668               C                A
 2        140668               C                B
 3        140668               C                C
 4        941214               A                A
 5        941214               A                B
 6        941214               A                C
 7        941214               B                A
 8        941214               B                B
 9        941214               B                C
10        945320               A                A
11        945320               A                B
12        945320               A                C
13        945320               B                A
14        945320               B                B
15        945320               B                C
16        945320               C                A
17        945320               C                B
18        945320               C                C

> names(aux)[2:3] = c("productCategory1","productCategory")
> result = inner_join(aux, data) %>% dcast(productCategory1~productCategory)


> result
  productCategory1 A B C
1                A 2 2 1
2                B 2 2 1
3                C 1 1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do that with `dplyr` and `tidyr`. I first `group_by` transactionID and then `expand` all possible combinations within those groups. Also, I think you have an error in your desired result. B and C appear together in only one order. So the last element of line 2 should be 1.

```
library(dplyr);library(tidyr)

data %>%
  group_by(transactionID)%>%
  expand(productCategory,productCategory)%>% 
  dcast(productCategory~productCategory1)

  productCategory A B C
1               A 2 2 1
2               B 2 2 1
3               C 1 1 2
```

Comment: Yes, I have an error. Thanks! I have just modified it. What is productCategory1¿?

Comment: @MarioM. It is created automatically by `expand` as you can't have two columns with the same name. (we are expanding a column on itself)

Comment: This code doesn't work for me. 'productCategory1' not found. If I run all code without dcast(), I have a dataframe with two columns: transactionID and productCategory (all possible combinations), not productCategory1.

Comment: sessionInfo(): tidyr_0.6.1 & dplyr_0.5.0

Comment: @MarioM. I have tidyr_0.7.2 and dplyr_0.7.4

Comment: I have just updated the packages. Solved with tidyr::expand(....). But output are a matrix of two's.